# C# windows 8 block style layout autosize

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

**

### Windowed

**
[image: Windowed]

**

### Maximized

**
[image: Maximized]

I want all the panels to auto size depending of `FormWindowState`, if is `Maximized` to adapt the height and width to screen size and look all good and without empty spaces if I will fill all the form with panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it by dividing the actual width to a specific percentage of height.

lets say you want your division to be 10/15/45/30

so in code:

```
double actualItemHeight = this.Height/ 0.10;
double actualItemWidth = this.Width/ 0.10;
```

i hope you get my point, you can create a method so you can reuse the code.

Comment: Can you give me an example for `panel1` or explain more briefly ?

Comment: @S0DDesign a panel has a Width and Height property, now for example it has a 100 Width, dividing 100 by 0.10 is equal to 10. so you set that value to your first panel. and so on.

Comment: I don`t want to size down the width or height of panels ... i want them to grow when i enter full screen so all of them looks like in normal form.

Comment: @S0DDesign it will, as you increase the window size it will increase, but when decrease it it will shrink >.>